# Unit testing an Observable (Subject<T>)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repository, system.reactive

I got a `Repository` with a public `Subject<Item>` called **Mutations** to which can be subscribed. It's easier to see the observable as a stream of `Item` of which  the source will primary be a socket connection.

I subscribe to the stream using something like `Repository.Mutations.Subscribe(item => DoWhatever(item));`.

I got a mocked datasource to which I want to push Items to test whether this Stream/Observable in the repository is doing it's job.

I've been reading a lot about using the `TestScheduler()` in Rx but I'm completely lost when trying to create a unit test and how this scheduler would come into play using my own code.

Admittedly I'm a beginner with Rx but I hope someone would be able to give me a hint or two.

Comment: I don't believe that you need to use the test scheduler if you aren't actually using interval or any other functions that use time.

Comment: Is it the Repository.Mutations function that you want to test or is it the "DoWhatever" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're after is to see if an item is produced by the `Mutations` property, you can do like you have, but just verify, in your test code, that the actual subscribe method has been called, i.e. something like:

```
Item expectedItem = new Item();
Item actualItem = null;
Repository.Mutations.Subscribe(item => actualItem = item);
dataSource.PushItem(expectedItem);

Assert.AreSame(expectedItem, actualItem);
```